# How to google sheets hyperlink 'cell text' as formula

Tags: google-sheets

Is it possible somehow to make a calculation in 'cell text' of Google sheets HYPERLINK formula?
This is not working:

=HYPERLINK("link.com","52.70*1.5")

I have already checked the internet and on this website for any available solution, but didn't find anything similar...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the double quotes to the label maybe

```
=HYPERLINK("link.com",52.7*1.5)
```

[image]